# I am not able to insert data into a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

If I try to insert data into a table I get an exception, but in the code I didn't find any errors.

Here is the code:

```
string conStr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WorkshopManagement; user id=sa; password=root";
string cmdStr = "insert into tbl_Workshop values (@WorkShopTitle, @WorkShopDate, @WorkshopDuration, @WorkShopTopics, null, null, null, null)";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkShopTitle", wP.WorkShopTitle);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkShopDate", wP.WorkShopDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopDuration", wP.WorkShopDuration);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkShopTopics", wP.WorkShopTopics);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

After this I got an exception like this, please help me to solve this exception. Is the exception thrown because of wrong connection string?

Error :

> iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131774469285624973): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: Maybe fix the connection string? You might also want to take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ You might also read the suggestion in the error message.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: 2 side notes: You should specify the columns in the `insert`, if the schema ever changes (columns added or changed position) it won't break the code. 2) Use `using` statements for your connection and command instances, this ensures the resouces are closed/disposed even in the event of an Exception.

Comment: Please share your table schema... My best guess is that your are missing to pass value for a not-null and non-default column. If not, the other most probable reason is that datatype in schema does not match with data being added to parameters.The exception you have shared is not the right one. If you can retrieve the text of SqlException, it would be much clearer what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your insert query because Insert query syntax is wrong...

insert into tbl_Workshop(WorkShopTitle,WorkShopDate,..) values (@WorkShopTitle, @WorkShopDate, @WorkshopDuration, @WorkShopTopics, null, null, null, null)